# Setting window size with Javascript Form Action

Tags: javascript

I have a page where I am getting session values then calling form action through javaScript, please see the code below

```
<%@ Page language="c#" AutoEventWireup="false" %>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" > 
<html>
  <head>
    <title>SessionRedirect</title>
    <meta name="GENERATOR" Content="Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 7.1">
    <meta name="CODE_LANGUAGE" Content="C#">
    <meta name=vs_defaultClientScript content="JavaScript">
    <meta name=vs_targetSchema content="http://schemas.microsoft.com/intellisense/ie5">
  </head>
  <body MS_POSITIONING="GridLayout">    
    <form method="post" name="frmRedirect" target="_blank">   
        <input type="hidden" name="email" value="<%=Session["Email"].ToString() %>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="pass" value="<%= Session["PWD"].ToString() %>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="User" value="<%= Session["User"].ToString() %>" />
     </form>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    if(frmRedirect.User.value == "P")
        {      
        frmRedirect.action = "http://cmsstag/partnerzone/index.aspx";       
      }
    else
        frmRedirect.action = "http://cmsstag/studentportal/index.aspx";

    document.frmRedirect.submit(); 
    location.replace("index.aspx");

</script>
<%
            Session.Remove("registration");
            Session.Remove("User");
            Session.Remove("UserId");
            Session.Remove("UserLoggedIn");
            Session.Remove("AgentCode");
            Session.Abandon();
%>  
  </body>
</html>
```

Now I want to open page in new window with size given by me when I use "frmRedirect.action" used in above code.

Comment: do you want to open this form in the new window or the action of the form?

Comment: I want it open the new window with form action

Comment: Could you change your "Seeting page size with Javascript Form Action" title to more appropriate "Setting window size with Javascript Form Action"

Comment: Is my question is valid or not as I am not getting any reply on this, please have look into it and provide me suitable solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a rather complicated example.
What you could try is:

1. open a new window first with javascript `window.open()` and set its dimensions **and name**
2. submit the form to it setting the correct target name as you've set it in `window.open()`

I've tried it. It works.

**Edit**
This is the code for you. Maybe you will have to set some time between opening a new window and submitting a form to make sure the window is already created (use `setTimeout`).

```
// open a new window with proper size    
window.open("", "MySubWindow", "height=480,width=640");

// do your action assignments

frmRedirect.target = "MySubWindow";
frmRedirect.submit();
location.replace("index.aspx");
```

Comment: Robert can you please give some code for what you are trying to say!

Comment: Thanks Robert, I have tested your code on machine, the problem now is that it is loosing the session values which I need on the opening page, please see the code above

Comment: Well you've removed all your session variables in the first page load, haven't you? No wonder there aren't any. Server-side code gets executed before the page is sent to the client. In your code example you 1) fill-in input form field, 2) remove Session variables and 3) return page to the client where form submission happens.

Comment: Sorry Robert, I am not able to understand your above comment can you please give me some example for it

Comment: Thanks Robert, I managed to do that, again thanks for your great help!

Comment: Excellent answer. Not only does this solve the issue, but it teaches you the real power of the target attribute which is not just limited to "_blank" values. There's like 20 SO questions similar to this one and this answer would've easily been the accepted answer on all 20. Gonna link this everywhere! Thank you!